# Unable to click on <a> tag on first click using angular & bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: html, angular, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here my issue is i unable to click on the  tags for the first click/first time  it is flickering and second click then it is performing its action.

```
<div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right landing-nav-text ul-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#about">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#info">info</a></li>


        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my CSS.

```
.navbar>li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {

    color: #788791;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px 3px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white !important;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a:hover {

    font-size: 14px;
    color: #788791;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #0f8287;
    margin-bottom: -3px;

}


.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    height: 20px;
}

.navbar {
    height: 20px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 0 0;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Below is my inspect element.

[image]
[image]

So here one the first click it is flicking and on the second click im able to perform the action  what may caused the issue ?

Comment: is this for the logout link? not sure I understand the question, paste your javascript

Comment: @Haris no it is not for louout it is for <a> tag present in nav & it is for all the issue is i am displaying links via <a> tag when ever i click on the <a> tag for the first time it is flickering/blinking and again if i click on it for the second time then it is going to that respective section

Comment: which browser are you using? i created a jsfiddle and seemed to be clickable just fine  with no fiddle. I am on the latest chrome version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @Haris yeah i too tried that but the issue is there and is my inspect element have you found any issue